# How to use the alt-tab-menu to switch immediately to the last used window [GNOME 3.32.2 @ Manjaro]

Tags: gnome, alt-tab, manjaro

If i pressed ALT + TAB on Windows, It just selects the last used window. On my gnome, it selects a random one (maybe sorted by application or so). I want the Windows behavior back. The first step was to change the view of the alt-tab-menu from applications to windows. I've done that as mentioned in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036248/how-to-separate-opened-windows-in-alttab-switcher-in-ubuntu-18-04) thread. But as before, it just selects a random windows, so if i want to quickly pause the podcast i was listening to in the background, to hear steps in like a shooter game, it would take so much longer. Does anyone have this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a cs:go problem, setting as solved.